# User network profile doesn't show no. questions/answers for area51

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, network-profile

The [accounts tab on my network profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/935589/gerrit?tab=accounts) doesn't show any questions or answers at area51:

[image: screenshot from profile page]

However, my [Area51 user page](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/60896/gerrit) *does* show that I have 3 questions and 1 answer:

[image: screenshot from area51 userpage]

Why aren't those shown in the network profile page?

Comment: This is a question for http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The question is about the [network profile accounts page](http://stackexchange.com/users/265671/jmort253?tab=accounts), not about the Area 51 page. This is on-topic on MSO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a bug really. This is how it appears for everybody. I have over 3800 reputation on Area 51, and no questions or answers are listed for me either.

This is because we're not *really* asking questions, and there are no answers to post. Area 51 is a staging area for new Q&A sites, and on Area 51, users gain reputation from creating new proposals and writing good, on-topic example questions.

What's more, you're actually referring to the ***Discussion*** part of Area 51, which is more like a per-site Meta than it is an actual parent site. Per site Meta questions and answers aren't displayed in your list of accounts, with the sole exception of Meta Stack Overflow. Therefore, the questions that you have displayed in your screenshot are actually from the Discussion (or meta) part of Area 51, not the *main* Area 51.

In short, this is by design.

Comment: Yep, you can't compare the numbers with any Q&A site...so they shouldn't appear in the same list.